# Computer Science

Tags: algorithms, algorithm-analysis, recurrence-relation, discrete-mathematics

I am trying to solve the following problem to find big-theta. I am having a lot of trouble, if anyone can help!

T(n)=8T(√n)+log^2(e^n)?

The logarithm is base 2 and is squared.

Comment: Look up the master theorem.

Comment: I don't think master theorem works here..

Comment: Try the substitution $S(m) = T(2^m)$, then apply the Master theorem.  If you refer to the duplicate, you'll find that one answer describes the substitution method, and one describes the Master theorem.